# Pandas: changing filtered dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to pass in a filtered dataframe into a function that is meant to manipulate some columns (again using filtering). I know this came up so many times already on SO, but even after reading the docs and other related questions, I have still problems getting my head around. I think I just need a working example from which I can start experimenting.

Here are my failed attempts. `s1` would be the value that's passed in to the column-manipulating function from my actual use case.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [ 8, 7, 6, 5]})
>>> df1
   a  b
0  1  8
1  2  7
2  3  6
3  4  5
>>> 
>>> s1 = df1.loc[df1['a']<=2, :]
>>> s1
   a  b
0  1  8
1  2  7
>>> s1['b'] = 0
__main__:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>>> df1
   a  b
0  1  8
1  2  7
2  3  6
3  4  5
>>> s1.loc[:, 'b'] = 0
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:508: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self.obj[item_labels[indexer[info_axis]]] = value
>>> df1
   a  b
0  1  8
1  2  7
2  3  6
3  4  5
>>> s2 = df1[df1['a']<=2] # next try: # this seems to create a detached copy of df1
>>> s2
   a  b
0  1  8
1  2  7
>>> s2.loc[:,'b']=0
>>> df1  # df1 didn't change :-(
   a  b
0  1  8
1  2  7
2  3  6
3  4  5
>>> s2   # ... only filtered copy of df1 did.
   a  b
0  1  0
1  2  0
```

Comment: What is it exactly that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am using a function `f(df)` that modifies some columns of a dataframe. I'd like to pass in a filtered dataframe transparently, if possible, so only a subset of rows get modified (in fact this function does some additional filtering and only modified a subset of the subset -- not sure if that's relevant).

Comment: I actually think that this isn't possible. You can't create a subset of a dataframe, change its data and expect the original dataframe to be changed, unless you do it all in one line using `ix`, `loc`, etc. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: I am going to bed.  The direction I was heading was to use `df.diff` to find when the next row changes or is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the function .ix

For example:

```
df1.ix[df1['a']<=2, 'b'] = 0
```

Is that you want to achieve?

Comment: No that doesn't work either. The equivalent for my use case would be `s3 = df1.ix[df1['a']<=2, :]` and then `s3['b'] = 4` (in a function that doesn't "know" anything about the filter) which doesn't change `df1`.

Comment: What you want to do is to have 0 for b where a <=2, right?